# How do I create a list from a webpage?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to create a list of words from the website [text](https://www.mit.edu/%7Eecprice/wordlist.10000). I would like to be able to randomise the word that is produced from this list using `random`. I hope this makes sense.

```
import random as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as rq


url = 'https://www.mit.edu/~ecprice/wordlist.10000'
page = rq.get(url)
soup = [BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')]

print(r.choice(soup))
```

I tried this but I get the full list. I presume this is due to the fact that the website I am scraping from does not use breaks or anything else so I am unsure how to specify what to take from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need of `BeautifulSoup` in this context, simply `split()` the text from the response into list.

##### Example

```
import random as r
import requests as rq


url = 'https://www.mit.edu/~ecprice/wordlist.10000'
word_list = rq.get(url).text.split()
print(r.choice(word_list))
```

If you really need to use `BeautifulSoup` you could `get_text()` and `split()`:

```
word_list = BeautifulSoup(rq.get(url).text).get_text('\n',strip=True).split()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `[BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')]`, the entire document will be converted as single element of the list. Instead convert into string and then use string split method to convert to list.

```
import random as r
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as rq


url = 'https://www.mit.edu/~ecprice/wordlist.10000'
page = rq.get(url)
soup = str(BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser'))
soup = soup.split('\n')
print(r.choice(soup))
```

Note: I wanted to use the same approach you used so that you will understand the difference.

Comment: I ended up using HedgeHog's approach but I appreciate you showing me how to do it using BeautifulSoup. It had totally slipped my to use `.string()`. Are both methods as effective or is one faster than the other, is there a significant difference in methods, other than code length?

Comment: General rule is : when you import more modules, the execution time will be more. (Though there are exceptions like numpy). So, the other one will be faster comparatively(slight difference, not much)